# C# - display information about custom objects in VS during debugging

Tags: c#

I have a set of C# classes, extending an abstract class. There is an abstract method `void Show()` on the parent. The extending classes are part of a graph with cycles. The implementations of Show invoke many times `Console.Write()`. Between the console writes there are recursive and other calls.

My problem - it is very hard to debug without an easy way to see the state of the graph. I've tried to make that method `string Show()`, but it is very hard to do properly with all the recursion and cycles. Can you suggest a better approach?

Thanks, Sam

Answer (score 2):

Consider using DebuggerDisplay rather than ToString. See these excellent articles:

- [Why override ToString()? Use DebuggerDisplayAttribute instead](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/soultech/archive/2011/04/05/whyoverridetostring_2d00_use_2d00_debuggerdisplayattribute_2d00_instead.aspx)
- [DebuggerDisplay attribute best practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2011/03/18/debuggerdisplay-attribute-best-practices.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

override your ToString() method, the tooltip window shown by the debugger uses this method to show any relevant data related to your object.

Comment: Those Show methods are 30-50 lines, with some funky indentation going on. I don't want to rewrite them.

Comment: you dont need to rewrite them, just make them return the shown text on the console and then return it by the ToString() method

Comment: "I've tried to make that method `string Show()`, but it is very hard to do properly with all the recursion and cycles."

Comment: this trick may help, make a private string buffer, when the show method is called, clear it, when a new line is shown on the console append it to the buffer, in the ToString() method, return that buffer.